# twitter4j api to post image to twitter,

Tags: image, twitter, twitter4j

I use twitter4j api to post image to twitter, initially my project worked without any exception but after further development it became unresponsive. Below is the error log form eclipse logcat.

> com.android.org.bouncycastle.jce.exception.ExtCertPathValidatorException: Could not validate certificate:
>   current time: Fri May 10 12:37:38 IST 2013, expiration time: Fri May 10 05:29:59 IST 2013
>   TwitterException{exceptionCode=[f69e96cd-138ff489 f69e96cd-138ff438 f69e96cd-138ff438 f69e96cd-138ff438 f69e96cd-138ff438], statusCode=-1, retryAfter=0, rateLimitStatus=null, version=2.1.6}

This happened since last night and I cant figure out whether this is due to twitter server error or not.

Comment: I am also getting the same error. Did you get the solution?

Answer (score -1):

Somehow it seems the Certs are linked to your current date/time and any modification made there will cause this exception. Even I'm hunting for a perfect answer/resolution to this issue.